# Arithmetic Sequence with conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

The question is:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be an arithmetic sequence with the following conditions: $S_{16} = 376$ and $a_{16} = 46$, where $S_n$ is the sum of terms $a_1$ through $a_n$.

Find $a_1$.

Comment: I think it doesn't really make much sense, could you reformulate the question so as we can understand it? What's $S$?

Comment: You should define what $S_{16}$ is in your question. My guess is that $S_n = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}a_k$, but there are other possible definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the two relevant formula for APs you have:

$$376=S_n=16\cdot a_1+\frac{16\cdot15}{2}d=16\cdot a_1+120d$$

$$46=a_n=a_1+15d$$

The first can be simplified to: 
$$\frac{47}{2}=a_1+\frac{7}{2}d$$
The second one minus this gives:
$$\frac{45}{2}=\frac{15}{2}d$$
$$d=3$$
Subbing $d$ back in gives:
$$a=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Use the formula

$$S_n=\frac n2(a_1+a_n)$$

where $S_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms, $a_1$ is the first term, and $a_n$ is the $n$th term.

The given data gives the values of all variables in that equation except $a_1$, so solve for it.